# SQL query for joining 2 tables with the help of 3rd table

Tags: mysql, sql

I've 3 tables in mysql:

```html
select *from mapping;

id,dept_id

id2,dept_id1

id3,dept_id2

select *from names;

id,name

id1,name1

id2,name2

id3,name3

select *from dept;

dept_id,dept_name

dept_id1,dept_name1

dept_id2,dept_name2

dept_id3,dept_name3
```

I've to return names from names table and dept_name from dept table, satisfying the condition given in mapping table.

A probable solution of getting required data:

```html
mysql> select names.name, dept.dept_name from names, dept, mapping where dept.dept_id = mapping.dept_id and names.id = mapping.id;
```

Comment: Not doing your homework for you. Sorry

Comment: If it is mysql, then you should add the mysql tag to your question.  Also it is expected that you show what you have tried with some sample data, the output and what you want as the output.  Possibly even a link to a SQL Fiddle so people can easily reproduce your problem

Comment: And you showed the mapping table twice. Typical many-to-many join, please feel free to research your assignment on SO. :)

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to join N tables, you need N-1 joins. So here, with three tables, you need two joins:

```
SELECT n.name, d.dept_name
FROM   names n
JOIN   mapping m ON n.id = m.id
JOIN   dept d ON d.dept_id = m.dept_id
```

Comment: in first line when we select name, dept_name, it's clear that name will be selected from names. But, how are we ensuring that dept_name is selected from dept?

Comment: @pzk both `name` and `dept_name` are unambiguous names (`name` only exists in `names`, `dept_name` only exists in `dept`), so you can just use them as is. But you're right - for better clarity, you can use fully qualified names (i.e., the form of `table_alias.column_name`). I've edited my answer to use such terms.

Comment: thanks for clarification.